# Deleted Question - What Gives?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

> [Question deletion has been reversed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238256/logitech-g13-changes-lcd-automatically-can-it-change-the-profile-automatically)

Yesterday, somebody did a drive-by down voting on a question I asked about how the Logitech G13 interacts with Star Trek Online. The question had been open and unanswered for about four months.

Today, the question is completely gone. How does this happen? Why is it allowed?

Comment: It was classified as a dead question. No answers, no positive score for over 30 days, so that single downvote probably pushed it into the cleanup pile. It had very little attention, too; 61 views.

Comment: Disappointing, really. I couldn't find any good resources on how the G13 actually works on the internet at large, so I figured a place dedicated to expert questions/expert answers would be the right place to look. Oh well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you stated that it didn't have any answer, it was probably removed by the [Community ♦ Bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

It actually fits this case:

> If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>   •has −1 or lower score
>   •has no answers
>   •is not locked

It was older than 30 days, it had no answers, it wasn't locked, and it was on -1.

Comment: Yeah, it does... So... Somebody doing a drive-by down-voting forced the  deletion, because nobody could provide an expert answer to a very narrow, and theoretically answerable question. Bummer.

Comment: @T.J.L. You're welcome to ask your question again, but keep in mind that that the fact your answer was deleted indicates folks didn't think it was that good of a question (or it wouldn't have a negative score). If you decide to reask I'd suggest seeing if there's some way you can improve your question.

Comment: @Wipqozn I don't have the text of the question any more, so I'd be reasking it from a blank slate. If I'm reading the privileges list right, you've got the rep to see the deleted question (I have no idea how you'd go about doing that, but it looks like it's within your capabilities). If there's something mechanically wrong with it, lemme know. If there's nothing wrong with it, it also looks like you have the rep to undelete it and maybe even upvote it so it doesn't get auto-deleted. Heck, if you can see who the drive-by down-voter was, rap 'em on the knuckles for me.

Comment: @T.J.L. If you have a link to the question I'm happy to take a look. If not, a mod (cc @AshleyNunn) might be able to provide it.

Comment: @Wipqozn No joy; seems you need the ability to see all deleted questions to even *find* your own deleted questions. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @T.J.L. I've taken a look and undeleted the question. :) Hopefully you'll be able to get some help with that issue now. :)

Comment: @AshleyNunn Thank you!